# Windows Phone: need to check Wi-Fi repeatedly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want my application to catch a moment when a particular Wi-Fi access point is available, even if app is closed or phone is rebooted. I suppose that the straightforward way to accomplish this task is to scan Wi-Fi access points repeatedly within a particular time interval. I need to do this every 2 minutes.

Android has AlarmManager class for this purpose, or I can catch event, when Wi-Fi scan results  become available.

There are background agents in Windows Phone but, as far as I know, I can't set custom time interval for repeating (30 minutes too long).

I also created GPS-tracking app, that worked in background, and implemented Wi-Fi check in onPositionChange method, but this "background task" was easy to be interrupted by pressing back button from app.

What is the better way to solve specified problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem, you might be trying to implement your own wi-fi based geofencing?

It's [already here](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/22/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-geolocation-and-geofencing/) in WP 8.1. The mechanism allows you to get location-based notifications even while your app is not running.

Comment: That's an interesting article. I will try to implement it, if no any other "simple" solution is found. Thank you.

Comment: This article lets us implement something more interesting than just binding to SSID of wireless network. Unfortunately, there is no API  to manage available networks, except those your are connected to.

Comment: For those, who really do not depend on wireless characteristics of network, and can use location instead, this answer is approach. That's why, for my case, I accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the "Internet Available" trigger described here:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/05/01/background-tasks-in-windows-store-apps.aspx

Comment: It would be good solution but I need to know when Wi-Fi access point is only available, not when phone is connected to it. Anyway, thanks for answer.

Comment: Ok, then i think this is not possible with the current Windows Phone API, or better: there is no trigger for that and creating a GPS tracking app is a hack and may be rejected during certification...